# Yii2 URL Manager Rules

Tags: php, url, yii2, rules

I have problem with create pretty url with URLManager Rules in yii2.

My SiteContoller have `actionProduct($slug)` and it generates url: `http://localhost/myweb/web/site/product?slug=new-product-name` and I would like create url like: `http://localhost/myweb/web/produkt/new-product-name`.

I tried to use some rules:

- `'site/product/<slug:\w+>' => 'produkt/<slug:\w+>',`
- `'<controller:\w+>/<slug:[A-Za-z0-9 -_.]+>' => 'produkt',`
- `'<controller:site>/<action:product>/<slug:\w+>' => 'produkt',`
- `'/site/product/<slug:\w+>' => 'produkt',`

but it's doesn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try `<slug:[\w\-]+>` as the part of left side URL rule.

Comment: sorry, but how left part of URL rule? `'<slug:[\w\-]+>' => 'produkt'` or something like `<controller:site>/<action:product>/<slug:[\w\-]+> => 'produkt'` ?

Comment: Depends on which rule you want. For example this: `'site/product/<slug:[\w\-]+>' => 'site/product',`

Comment: ok, it works. But when I change it to `'site/product/<slug:[\w\-]+>' => 'produkt'` still don't work

Comment: `'produkt'` means the rule maps it to `produkt/index` by default. Do you have `ProduktController` with `actionIndex($slug)`?

Comment: don't have. But can I create custom rule? Others framework allow do this

Comment: Of course you can. You need to read more about `UrlManager` because you obviously are missing something. If you want `produkt/telewizor` point to `site/product` add `'produkt/<slug:[\w\-]+>' => 'site/product'`.